# SSRS Report SUM IF

Tags: reporting-services

Working on a ssrs report I ran into a problem.

In case that the Opening balance (the first row) is recorded as an Income, the Balance in the upper right corner

[image: a]

Should be reduced by the value shown in the "Income" cell for the Opening Balance row.

In case that the Opening Balance is recorded as Expenses the expression should stay as it is.

This is the expression for the Balance cell: `=Sum(Fields!Income.Value-Fields!Expenses.Value)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear here.  What value are you currently getting and what are you expecting (and where) in your screenshot?

Comment: Okay. The value in the Balance cell (the one in the upper right corner ) should be reduced by the amount of the Opening balance only in case that it is in the Income Column. In this particular case the balance should be 0 EUR. If the Opening Balance value is in Expenses column the expression for that balance cell should be: =Sum(Fields!Income.Value-Fields!Expenses.Value)

Comment: What does your dataset look like?

Comment: It's a stored procedure with Apt as a parameter.                             
@Apt nchar(10)
AS
SELECT        dbo.Apartments.Apt_ID AS Expr1, dbo.Apartments.Apt, dbo.Apartments.Sq_m_, dbo.Trans.Date, dbo.Trans.Apt_ID, dbo.Trans.Description_ID, dbo.Trans.Income, dbo.Trans.Expenses, dbo.Descr.Desc_ID, dbo.Descr.Description, 
dbo.Trans.Trans_ID, dbo.Trans.Income - dbo.Trans.Expenses AS Balance, dbo.Trans.Balance AS Expr2, dbo.Trans.Memo, dbo.Trans.Fees_Due, dbo.Apartments.OwnerName, dbo.Apartments.OwnerEmail

Comment: FROM            dbo.Apartments INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Trans ON dbo.Apartments.Apt_ID = dbo.Trans.Apt_ID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Descr ON dbo.Trans.Description_ID = dbo.Descr.Desc_ID
       WHERE Apt=@Apt

Comment: Please add any additional details or code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you need to take the balance, subtract the income and add the expenses from the row in your dataset that contains the description "opening balance...".

This could be achieved by using the initial balance calculation that you already have and doing a lookup to get the income/expense for the "opening balance..." line item based on the first 15 characters of the description ("Opening Balance"):

```
=Sum(Fields!Income.Value-Fields!Expenses.Value) - Lookup("Opening Balance", Left(Fields!Description.Value, 15), Fields!Income.Value, "DatasetName") + Lookup("Opening Balance", Left(Fields!Description.Value, 15), Fields!Expenses.Value, "DatasetName")
```

I'm guessing that this won't work out of the box and that you may have to test for nothing or COALESCE your database values and/or cast your fields to get this to work.  Impossible to say exactly without seeing your actual dataset.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Problem solved. Had to find other way.